# Blender crashes when baking line art (2.93)

Tags: objects

Using Windows 2.93 build from yesterday or 28th May.

Trying to bake line art to simple static scene Blender crashes every single time. Anyone else?

The exact point in this video is what I'm trying to do (not my video).
https://youtu.be/pubuwjlgFZg?t=112

I have created a simple scene with a plane and Suzanne
Select Suzanne
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> > *Grease Pencil* add *Object Line Art
Modifier* go to *Properties > Baking > Bake Line Art*

Instant Crash!

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug (which with daily builds I understand can happen)?

In the video above the poster must be using an earlier version since there is no "Object Line Art" option when she creates it, only Collection and Scene.

Comment: Leaving this here in case someone else has the same problem....
I discovered that you have to UNSELECT ALL before doing the baking.... That's it. Simple.

Comment: If you could, please use the answer thing below to put the solution. Then tick off the check to say that it is the solution so the question turns green.